# Authenticate user with Azure AD on .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm writing an API in .NET Core 2.0 that needs to get details from a jwt issed by Azure AD. In my actions I want to access the user identity object to get their username, etc. I have attempted to do this as below, but all requests are responded to with 401.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAzureAd(this IServiceCollection services, AzureAdOptions options)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = options.Authority;
            o.Audience = options.Audience;
        });
    return services;
}
```

The authority I am using is "https://login.microsoftonline.com" and the audience is "https://OURDOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com/OURAPPLICATIONNAME".

I even tried the below and had no success.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAzureAd(this IServiceCollection services, AzureAdOptions options)
{
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SECRET"));
    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false
            };
            o.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            o.Authority = options.Authority;
            o.Audience = options.Audience;
        });
    return services;
}
```

Comment: This `o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` is wrong. Just use `.UseAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I posted an old code snippet, please check it now. The code you gave me threw the exception "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."

Comment: If you look at the logs generated by ASP.NET Core, don't you see an invalid issuer message? I had to add to `options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers`: `https://sts.windows.net/ID` and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/ID` where ID is the id of the domain. There's an `option.` that enables detailed error messages

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The only thing I can really see is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: (null)." in the output window.

Comment: Did you add `services.AddMvc()` in `ConfigureServices` and `app.UseAuthentication().UseMvc()` in `Configure`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes

Comment: Authority should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id`. Replace tenant-id with your Azure AD id or one of the verified domains, e.g. tenantname.onmicrosoft.com. Or if this is multi-tenant, replace tenant-id with `common`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried both of these, both still return 401.

Comment: @JacobMason Can you edit your question so that it only include the latest you have? For both Configure and ConfigureServices if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by using the to the below.

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = options.AADInstance + options.TenantId;
    o.Audience = options.Audience;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = $"{options.AADInstance}{options.TenantId}/v2.0"
    };
});
```